# maven file.encoding and Charset.defaultCharset()

Tags: maven, encoding

my maven parent POM contains

```
<file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

and I have a JUnit-Test which contains the following code:

```
byte[] bytes;
System.out.println("------------------" + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
try {
    bytes = "ü".getBytes(); // german umlaut u - two bytes in utf-8 one byte in latin-1
    System.out.println("Byte count: " + bytes.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%02x", bytes[i]));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("------------------" + Charset.defaultCharset());
```

When I run mvn clean test (on my windows machine with a default charset of Cp1252) the output is

```
------------------Cp1252
Byte count: 1
fc
------------------windows-1252
```

When I run mvn -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean test the output is:

```
------------------UTF-8
Byte count: 1
fc
------------------windows-1252
```

Now I have two questions:

1) What is the property <file.encoding> in my POM good for?

2) When I specified -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 why wasn't the default charset changed to UTF-8 (and therefore getBytes() still used 'cp1252' and returns 1 byte) and how do I change this

Thanks in advance,

Ronald

Answer (score 0):

The editor must set the same encoding too. Evidently you saved the file in Cp1252. Use JEdit or NotePad++ to check that.

```
getBytes("UTF-8"); // 2
getBytes("Cp1252"); // 1
getBytes(); // Depending on platform, System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

What maven does with those properties, I am not entirely sure in case of `file.encoding`.

Comment: Hi Joop, the Java source file has been saved as UTF-8. Also it would not explain why the call to Charset.defaultCharset() still returns "windows-1252" in the second result. And I guess the default charset is the main culprid why "ü".getBytes() returns 1 byte. If the default charset was UTF-8 it would return 2 bytes - as it does when I call "ü".getBytes("UTF-8").

Comment: I have extended the answer.

Comment: Hi Joop, I agree with the code you pasted. Especially the 3rd line is relevant - getBytes() uses the default platform charset. But this does not answer my question. The real question is why Charset.defaultCharset() still returns "Cp1252" and getBytes() still uses "Cp1252" after I specified -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8.

Comment: `Charset.defaultCharset()` looks at an initially null static field. The first time it tries the property `file.encoding`, otherwise UTF-8. The following times it yields the static field. So it must be that maven too early invokes `Charset.defaultCharset()`.

Comment: Hi Joop, this is what it looks like when one looks at the OpenJDK source code. But this would mean that when you have a class just containing a main method with System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset()); and do not specify -Dfile.encoding it would return UTF-8. If I try this on my machine it still returns "windows-1252". I am using Oracle JDK "1.7.0_07".

Comment: The System.getProperties are first filled by native code; on the command line with -D one simply overrides them. So on your Windows the default charset is Winodws-1252.

Comment: Hi Joop, this sounds logical and explains the behaviour of my little test from two comments earlier. The remaining question is why System.getProperty("file.encoding") == "UTF-8" and Charset.defaultCharset() == "windows-1252" when I run "When I run mvn -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean test". Thanks for your interest in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have Charset.defaultCharset returning UTF-8 you need to set it for the plugin argLine as well, because its too late if you specify it only in the properties.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
      <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
      <argLine>${surefireArgLine} -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```